# How to get public Location of user with public access token?

Tags: facebook, location

I have tried searching it a lot, but can't come up with a relevant answer. I can see the location of the person when i browse their facebook profile, e.g https://www.facebook.com/nitin.karkera has made his location public.

but using graph api explorer, i can't get the location with this call

> nitin.karkera?fields=id,name,location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Documentation clearly states you can't.  Only option is to scrape the Facebook webpage and wait for their legal department to contact you.

Comment: Could you provide a link to that specific part of the documentation so we can all read it for ourselves?

Comment: Literally the first thing when you google 'facebook scraping'
https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

Comment: But if people are reading this answer here, we should provide that link here as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the permission : `friends_location`/ `user_location`. Try the same code after setting this permission.

Comment: I need to access the information as a public user (not from the user of my app).... I can see this information right now... why can't i retrieve it using graph api?